# HTML error codes from Nu HTMl checker

Tags: html

For each question I am about to ask, the same response came from you guys from other questioners."Alternatively, can you include relevant portions of your page in the question?" I am going to provide the content you request to solve my issues. Please advise.

> Error: No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.     From line 371,
>   column 111; to line 371, column 114      title="">
>
> ↩
>   Error: No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.     From line 372,
>   column 169; to line 372, column 172      alt="" />↩
>   Error: End tag div seen, but there were open elements.     From line
>   375, column 1; to line 375, column 6     p>↩↩↩
>   Error: Unclosed element a.     From line 371, column 1; to line 371,
>   column 110      315px;">↩↩<     Error: Start tag a seen but an
>   element of the same type was already open.     From line 377, column
>   1; to line 377, column 117      315px;">↩↩<     Error: End tag a violates nesting
>   rules.     From line 377, column 1; to line 377, column 117
>   315px;">↩↩<     Fatal Error: Cannot recover after
>   last error. Any further errors will be ignored.     From line 377,
>   column 1; to line 377, column 117      315px;">↩↩<

Now here is the corresponding content in question:

```
<div style="width: 960px;">
  <div id="leftColumn" style="float: left; width: 315px;">
    <a  href="http://homesinestrellamountain.com/11280-s-wilson-lane-goodyear-az-85338/" target="_blank" title="">
      <div id="up-1st" class="ft-3up">
        <img src="http://i102.photobucket.com/albums/m107/azhousing/11280%20S%20Wilson%20Lane%20Goodyear%20AZ%2085338_zpscxxeckxo.jpg" alt=""/>
        <p class="search-button">11280 S WILSON LANE</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="middlecolumn" style="float: left; width: 315px;">
     <a  href="http://homesinestrellamountain.com/16477-w-san-pedro-cir-goodyear-arizona-85338/" target="_blank" title="">
       <div id="up-2nd" class="ft-3up">
         <img src="http://i102.photobucket.com/albums/m107/azhousing/16477%20W%20SAN%20PEDRO%20CIR_zpsrd09l2zj.jpg" alt="" />
         <p class="search-button">16477 W SAN PEDRO CIR</p>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: You never Close your `<a></a>`tag.

Comment: Do you have a Picture, how it should look like?

Comment: clearer formatting

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your `<a>`-tag and your `<div>`. These are only your errors. The conent of the code is the same. This should work:

```
<div style="width: 960px;">
  <div id="leftColumn" style="float: left; width: 315px;">
    <a href="http://homesinestrellamountain.com/11280-s-wilson-lane-goodyear-az-85338/" target="_blank" title="">
      <div id="up-1st" class="ft-3up">
        <img src="http://i102.photobucket.com/albums/m107/azhousing/11280%20S%20Wilson%20Lane%20Goodyear%20AZ%2085338_zpscxxeckxo.jpg" alt=""> 
      </div>
    </a>
    <p class="search-button">11280 S WILSON LANE</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="middlecolumn" style="float: left; width: 315px;">
  <a  href="http://homesinestrellamountain.com/16477-w-san-pedro-cir-goodyear-arizona-85338/" target="_blank" title="">
    <div id="up-2nd" class="ft-3up">
      <img src="http://i102.photobucket.com/albums/m107/azhousing/16477%20W%20SAN%20PEDRO%20CIR_zpsrd09l2zj.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <p class="search-button">16477 W SAN PEDRO CIR</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It cleared the error codes but the page does not display correctly. The address boxes are missing and when you zoom in on the page, the photos disappear. I changed the code back to what I had before. If you go to http://homesinestrellamountain.com, you can see how the featured listings should be displayed.